# SwiftUI Drag And Drop with List

Tags: list, swiftui, drag-and-drop

I try to implement drag and drop between two views as shown in the code bellow, when I embed the "ForEach" view inside Group its work well, but when I try to embed it in the "List" view it doesn't work and I don't know why, any one can help to solve this problem ??

```
import SwiftUI
import MobileCoreServices


struct DragAndDropExample: View {
    
    var delegate = dropDelegate()
    @State var data = [SomeData(id: 1), SomeData(id: 2), SomeData(id: 3), SomeData(id: 4), SomeData(id: 5)]
    @State var selectedDate: [SomeData] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 16) {
            
            Group {   // Try to maek this "List"
                ForEach(data) { dat in
                    
                    Image(systemName: "\(dat.data).square.fill")
                        .resizable()
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                        .cornerRadius(15)
                        
                        .onDrag{
                            NSItemProvider(item: .some(URL(string: dat.data)! as NSSecureCoding), typeIdentifier: String(kUTTypeURL))
                        }
                }
            }
            
            Group {   // Try to maek this "List"
                if selectedDate.isEmpty {
                    Text("Drop Here")
                }else {
                    ForEach(selectedDate) { dat in
                        Text("\(dat.data)")
                    }
                }
            }
            .background(Color.blue)
            .onDrop(of: [String(kUTTypeURL)], delegate: delegate)
        }
    }
}

struct DragAndDropExample_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DragAndDropExample()
    }
}

class SomeData: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let data: String
    init(id: Int) {
        self.id = id
        self.data = String(id)
    }
}

class dropDelegate: DropDelegate {
    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        // Drag and drop code here...
        return true
    }
}
```